# CSS block-quote empty lines

Tags: php, html, css, blockquote

CSS block quote don't add empty lines to the qoute

example :

```
<blockquote>
this is number 1

this is number  2
</blockquote>
```

this will appear as the following but the `"" > ""` don't appear and only empty line appear

```
> this is number 1

>

> this is number 2
```

i want them empty line to be included on the blockquote .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `>` is a reserved character in HTML. It's used for building tags.

You need to escape it, or the browser will think it's code and not display it.

Use `&lt;` for `<`, and `&gt;` for `>`.

```html
<blockquote>
this is number 1<br>
&gt;<br><!-- with "greater than" symbol -->
this is number  2<br>
</blockquote>
<hr>
<blockquote>
this is number 1<br>
<br><!-- with just an empty line -->
this is number  2<br>
</blockquote>
```

*From the spec:*

> [**5.3.2 Character entity
>   references**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2)
>
> Four character entity references deserve special mention since they
>   are frequently used to escape special characters:
>
> - `&lt;` represents the `<` sign.
> - `&gt;` represents the `>` sign.
> - `&amp;` represents the `&` sign.
> - `&quot;` represents the `"` mark.
>
> Authors wishing to put the `<` character in text should use `&lt;`
>   (ASCII decimal 60) to avoid possible confusion with the beginning of a
>   tag (start tag open delimiter). Similarly, authors should use `&gt;`
>   (ASCII decimal 62) in text instead of `>` to avoid problems with older
>   user agents that incorrectly perceive this as the end of a tag (tag
>   close delimiter) when it appears in quoted attribute values.